# Should the kube-bench job/pod run on every node in a Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kube-bench

I am currently in a doubt on how to properly run kube-bench in my cluster (AKS cluster to be specific).
I used of course the job definition file from [github](https://github.com/aquasecurity/kube-bench/blob/main/job-aks.yaml), and modified it to run it as a cronjob (it is maybe an overkill but it isn't relevant in my question). This definition runs the pod in the default namespace, and I changed it as well to use a newly create kube-bench namespace. Furthermore, it runs it only on one node, and as I understood it, it runs the tests only on that node in this case.
So my questions would be:

1. is it a good practice to run it in separated namespace intended only for kube-bench?
2. If I have more nodes (and nodepools) in a cluster, do I need to run the job/pod on every node (eg. as an daemonset), and collect the report for every node individually?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. I would generally advise to not use the default namespace, but whatever organization and separation makes sense for your setup is fine. 2. AFAIK kube-bench is only for the k8s platform itself, you will need a seperate tool if you also wish to check on the security of the OS on the nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late response.
Just for record once again. So, it doesn't matter on which node kube-bench runs? It checks only the platform and it is totally fine to run it as a job out-of-the-box?